# Bottom overflow 13 pixels

Tags: flutter

[image]

[image]

How can fix it?

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.loose,
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: buildSearch(),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Container(color: Colors.green),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text('Frequitly Visited'),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Show More'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 6,
                child: buildSites(size),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  buildSearch() {
    return Container(
      child: FloatingSearchBar(
        transitionCurve: Curves.easeInOutCubic,
        transition: CircularFloatingSearchBarTransition(),
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        builder: (context, _) => _history(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container buildSites(size) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black,
      width: size.width,    
    );
  }

 
  Widget _history() {
    List<String> listHistory = [
      'Flutter',
      'Python',
      'Nodejs',
      'Rails',
    ];
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      child: Material(
        child: Column(
          children: listHistory
              .map((e) => ListTile(
                    title: Text(e),
                    onTap: () {},
                  ))
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to fixed the height of search & container, expanded only flexible part:

```
Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 100,
                child: buildSearch(),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 100,
                child: Container(color: Colors.green),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text('Frequitly Visited'),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Show More'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: buildSites(size),
              )
            ],
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the Expanded widget wrapped around your `buildSearch()` widget and give a desired padding or you can also your sizedbox with a desiredHeight below and above the buildSearch()

so basically change

```
...

Expanded(
  flex: 2,
  child: buildSearch(),
),

...
```

to

```
...
Padding(
  padding:EdgeInsets.only(top:20,bottom:50), // adding a suitable padding should fix it
  child:buildSearch(),
)
...
```